# Javascript convert table header having multiple rows to divs

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm in javascript language that will read a table header and then return equivalent DIVs in either a string OR as an object of DOM. The header looks like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">MinistryCode</th>
       <th rowspan="2">MinistryName</th>
       <th colspan="2">1390</th>
       <th colspan="2">1391</th>
       <th colspan="2">1392</th>
    </tr>

     <tr>
       <th>Target</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
       <th>Target</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
       <th>Target</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I think better to put table in div block and use same table as it is. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have this look and feel then you have to rely on CSS. I don't know why do you want to create this table using DIVs.[see this example](http://jsbin.com/eROHiQa/8/edit)

```
table{
  border:1px solid;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  table-layout:fixed;
  text-align:center;
}
thead th{
  background-color:#D2E7FA;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}

thead tr:first-child th + th{
  width:40%!important;
}
thead tr+tr th{
  width:9%!important;
}

tbody tr td{
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I require a JS Function which returns the header equivalent in DIV. No need to change the actual table.